# How to know element position while it move

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is way to obtain x,y data of a moving element (**while** it move...), something like:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX,
    y = e.pageY;
...
}
```

but referred to a specific element (i.e. **$("#mydiv")**)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `pageX`/`pageY` variables in the `event` object refers to the mouse position. If you want to get the position of the element you should do something like this:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var element = $('#myDiv');
    console.log( element.offset() );
    // returns an object with x/y coordinates of the top-left corner of the element
});
```

Checkout the documentation for [`.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) for more info.

Comment: Doesn't even answers the question